# Exported tflite model predicts incorrect outputs

Tags: ios, firebase-mlkit

I have a trained custom Tensorflow model and want to use it in my iOS app via Firebase MLKit.
The model is a simple 4in-4out neural network with one hidden layer which is like this.

```
num_data_input = 4
num_units = 12
num_display = 4

xd = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_data_input])

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_data_input, num_units],dtype=tf.float32))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units],dtype=tf.float32))
hidden1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(xd, w1) + b1)

w0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_units, num_display],dtype=tf.float32))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_display],dtype=tf.float32))
p = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden1, w0) + b0)

ref = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,num_display])
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(ref * tf.log(p))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(p, 1), tf.argmax(ref, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

The objective of this model is by using 4 source signals separately placed in a room  predict which one you are closest to among 4 anchor points set in the room. So the output should show the probability for each anchor point. 
(The relationship between the source signal positions and the anchor points is not straight-forward and that's why I'm considering using machine learning, by the way.)

After the training of about 10000 iterations the `loss` has declined to about 0.3. (Which is not good enough but it's not a problem here).

Right after the training, I got the values like this.

```
print("input", dataarray[0][0])
print("output", sess.run(p, {xd: np.array(dataarray[0][0], dtype=np.float32).reshape(1,4)}))
# Results in:
# input [-87.43277416700528, -81.06589379945419, -71.74611110703701, -71.10851819430701]
# output [[1.5792685e-14 1.7755997e-01 7.4530774e-01 7.7132232e-02]]

print("input", dataarray[10][0])
print("output", sess.run(p, {xd: np.array(dataarray[10][0], dtype=np.float32).reshape(1,4)}))
# Results in:
# input [-86.87348060585144, -79.92684778533435, -71.24158331694396, -71.81342917898614]
# output [[1.30361505e-14 1.73598051e-01 7.51829445e-01 7.45724738e-02]]
```

Apart from it's correct or not, you can at least see it is reporting different values for different input.

Having this result, I made a tflite model with `saved_model` in python code

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, "model", inputs={"input": xd}, outputs={"output": p})
```

and tflite_convert from commandline

```
tflite_convert --output_file=tmp/model.tflite --saved_model_dir=model
```

Then import it in my Swift project through the cloud:

```
    let conditions = ModelDownloadConditions(isWiFiRequired: true, canDownloadInBackground: true)
    let cloudModelSource = CloudModelSource(
        modelName: "my-model",
        enableModelUpdates: false,
        initialConditions: conditions,
        updateConditions: conditions
    )
    let registrationSuccessful = ModelManager.modelManager().register(cloudModelSource)

    let options = ModelOptions(
        cloudModelName: "my-model",
        localModelName: nil)
    interpreter = ModelInterpreter.modelInterpreter(options: options)

    ioOptions = ModelInputOutputOptions()
    do {
        try ioOptions.setInputFormat(index: 0, type: .float32, dimensions: [1, 4])
        try ioOptions.setOutputFormat(index: 0, type: .float32, dimensions: [1, 4])
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to set input or output format with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

and perform the prediction:

```
    // 1st value
    let inputValues: [Double] = [-78.07635984967995, -76.68000728404165, -73.98016027165527, -74.77428875130332] 
    // 2nd value
    // let inputValues: [Double] = [-86.87348060585144, -79.92684778533435, -71.24158331694396, -71.81342917898614]

    let inputs = ModelInputs()
    let converted: [Float32] = inputValues.map { Float32($0) }
    do {
        try inputs.addInput([converted])
    } catch let error {
        print("Failed to add input: \(error)")
    }

    interpreter.run(inputs: inputs, options: ioOptions) { (outputs, error) in
        guard error == nil, let outputs = outputs else { return }
        do {
            if let ov = try outputs.output(index: 0) as? [[NSNumber]] {
                print("output = \(ov)") 
                // output = [[0.089901, 0.2951571, 0.2564065, 0.3585353]]
                // ^ Different from above result in python!
                //   And gives me the same value even when the input value is switched to "2nd value" above
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("output retrieval error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly, the output value from the Swift code is different from the one in Python.
And on top of that, I tried with some different values they all give me the same value. I also tried with the real world signal value, but it gave me the same value in almost all cases.
Only when I give it some extreme values far out of my expected range it shows different values.

Do you see any problem in my Python code or Swift code?
Or anything missing in my tflite model conversion?

Any information is helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Partly solved. 
Or accurately saying, it was a different issue.

By providing the model from local bundle it worked as expected.

I found that even I replaced the model on the cloud the app kept using the previous model.

I didn't mentioned above but I tried different tflite models before getting the result above.  And I didn't pay much attention about its first result as I knew the model was quite incomplete.  If I paid more attention to it I'd have found earlier that the result wasn't changing at all.

Anyways I now have to figure out why the retrieval from the cloud won't work as expected, but I hope this info helps someone else.